# Pandas + CountVectorizer: how to filter rows quickly

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a text column in Pandas:

```
df['TEXT_COL']
```

then I apply *CountVectorizer* to it:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
v = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['TEXT_COL'])
```

and getting a set of words/features:

```
ft = v.get_feature_names()
```

and a TDM:

```
m = vectorizer.transform(df['TEXT_COL'])
```

**I need:** slice of *df* which contains only rows that contain particular feature from feature_set *ft*.

How to get it?

**Pandas setup:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('Word'), ('Word Sea Ocean'), ('Tree'), ('Forest Tree')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['TEXT_COL']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
v = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['TEXT_COL'])

ft = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
m = vectorizer.transform(df['TEXT_COL'])
```

[image]

> for f in ft:
>
> ???

Comment: can you show / post your desired data set? If you are going to search for ALL features then you will get almost all rows (except those containing ONLY stopwords)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small demo:

```
# execute your setup script ...

In [48]: vectorizer.vocabulary_
Out[48]: {'forest': 0, 'ocean': 1, 'sea': 2, 'tree': 3, 'word': 4}
```

`m` is a sparse matrix

```
In [49]: m
Out[49]:
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

we can convert it to regular numpy array:

```
In [50]: m.toarray()
Out[50]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

how to list a particular feature:

```
In [51]: m[:, vectorizer.vocabulary_['sea']].toarray()
Out[51]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int64)
```

or using `ft`:

```
In [57]: m[:, ft.index('sea')].toarray()
Out[57]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int64)

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
         TEXT_COL
0            Word
1  Word Sea Ocean
2            Tree
3     Forest Tree
```

Let's show all rows containing feature `'tree'`:

```
In [71]: idx = m[:, ft.index('tree')] == 1

In [72]: df[idx.toarray()]
Out[72]:
      TEXT_COL
2         Tree
3  Forest Tree
```

or just like this:

```
In [77]: df[m[:, ft.index('tree')].astype(bool).toarray()]
Out[77]:
      TEXT_COL
2         Tree
3  Forest Tree
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much.

Comment: @DenisKulagin, glad i could help :)